# Install mongoid gem in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I'm trying to install `mongoid` gem in Rails 4 following [these instructions](https://gorails.com/guides/setting-up-rails-4-with-mongodb-and-mongoid) (first link on google, and other instructions say the same thing).

Added the following lines to my `Gemfile` and ran `bundle install`.

```
gem 'mongoid', '~> 4', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
gem 'bson_ext'
```

This yields an error:

```
Fetching git://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=Connection refused

Retrying git clone 'git://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git' "/home/mike/.bundler/cache/git/mongoid-176c799a8a4589043b073e277e545d697119fa82" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet due to error (2/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git' "/home/mike/.bundler/cache/git/mongoid-176c799a8a4589043b073e277e545d697119fa82" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /home/mike/shares has failed.
```

The [mongoid/mongoid GitHub repository](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid) says it has moved to [mongodb/mongoid](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid). But changing `gem` line to `github: 'mongodb/mongoid'` does not fix the issue.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection refused error probably means that you are behind a firewall that blocks the git protocol port , using `https:443` probably your firewall allows

You can use something like,

`gem 'mongoid', :git => 'https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid.git'`

Comment: Hmm it still gives me the `connection refused` error.